# Using sinon how to avoid testing nested function?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I'm using mocha/chai/sino and I'm new with the three of them.

```
const a = () => {
  b();
}

const b = () => {
  console.log('here');
}
```

In this example I just want to test that `b` is been called when calling `a` without executing `b`.

Something like:

```
it('test', () => {
  const spy = sinon.spy(b);
  a();
  chai.expect(spy.calledOnce).to.be.true;
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sinon's `stub` is what you are looking for.

[Sinon Stubs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/)

> When to use stubs?
> Use a stub when you want to:
>
> 1. Control a method’s behavior from a test to force the code down a specific path. Examples > include forcing a method to throw an error in order to test error handling.
> 2. **When you want to prevent a specific method from being called directly** (possibly because it triggers undesired behavior, such as a XMLHttpRequest or similar).

```
it('test', () => {
  const stub = sinon.stub(b);
  a();
  chai.expect(stub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
})
```